# Transforming two 3D vectors into each other gives different Euler angles

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, homogeneous-spaces, project-euler

Lets take two vectors A and B represented in x,y,z(metres) and Euler angles XYZr(deg) as

```
A =

   -0.0036    0.1235   -0.9213  120.2176   -0.4881  -87.1283


B =

   -0.1241   -0.0112   -1.1028  -58.4000    1.6000   92.1000
```

Converting them to 4x4 Homogeneous matrix gives

```
M_A =

    0.0501    0.9987   -0.0085   -0.0036
    0.5023   -0.0326   -0.8641    0.1235
   -0.8632    0.0390   -0.5033   -0.9213
         0         0         0    1.0000
    
    
M_B =

   -0.0366   -0.9989    0.0279   -0.1241
    0.5245    0.0046    0.8514   -0.0112
   -0.8506    0.0458    0.5238   -1.1028
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

Transform B into A and A into B gives

```
M_BA = inv(M_B) * M_A
M_AB = inv(M_A) * M_B

M_BA =

    0.9959   -0.0868   -0.0248   -0.0882
   -0.0873   -0.9960   -0.0185   -0.1114
   -0.0231    0.0206   -0.9995    0.2131
         0         0         0    1.0000


M_AB =

    0.9959   -0.0873   -0.0231    0.0830
   -0.0868   -0.9960    0.0206   -0.1230
   -0.0248   -0.0185   -0.9995    0.2088
         0         0         0    1.0000
```

Converting M_BA and M_AB into Euler angles gives

```
angles_BA =

  178.9396   -1.4222    4.9837


angles_AB =

 -178.8198   -1.3244    5.0105
```

I was thinking that angles_BA and angles_AB should be same. But, they are not.
****Why there is a difference between angles_BA and angles_AB ??****

Comment: What kind of 3D vector has six coordinates? How is it transformed into a homogeneous matrix?

Comment: @DavidK just edited the question - its in xyz and euler angles

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are doing now (maybe). I would not call $A$ and $B$ "vectors". They are lists of parameters encoding translation-rotations. There are dozens of ways to interpret such a list, depending on order of operations, world coordinates vs. body coordinates, etc.

Comment: How much is the difference between angles in the end if you work out each matrix entry to $15$ decimal digits instead of keeping only four decimal digits?

Comment: Even after using the full precision, the error stays exactly the same. The error is about 0.13 degrees in each angle

Answer (score 1):

You have two *isometric transformations*, $A$ and $B$,
each of which is a combined translation and rotation.

Let's define some useful notation.
Define $T_{X,Y,Z}$ as the matrix for a translation by $X$ units in the $x$ direction,
$Y$ units in the $y$ direction, and $Z$ units in the $z$ direction.
Define $R_{x;\theta}$ as the matrix for a rotation by the angle $\theta$ around the $x$ axis; likewise $R_{y;\theta}$ and $R_{z;\theta}$ for rotations around the $y$ and $z$ axes, respectively.

Also, let's write our angles in radians.

With a little help from WolframAlpha, I think I have deduced that $A$ is actually the transformation whose matrix is
$$
M_A = T_{-0.0036,0.1235,-0.9213} R_{x;2.09819} R_{y;-0.008519} R_{z;-1.52068}.
$$

That is, first you rotate by $-1.52068$ radians around the $z$ axis;
then $-0.008519$ radians around the $y$ axis; then $2.09819$ around the $x$ axis;
and finally you translate by the vector $(-0.0036,0.1235,-0.9213)^T.$
Note that the matrix on the **right** is the one whose transformation is applied **first**, because you apply the transformation by putting any coordinates you want transformed in a column vector on the right side of the matrix $M_A,$
and when you expand $M_A$ into a product of component transformations like this the rightmost matrix is closest to the column vector and is the first to be multiplied with it.

We could also say that $A$ is a rotation by $2.40815$ radians ($137.977$ degrees) around the axis through the origin in the direction of the vector
$(0.674519, 0.638394, -0.370778)^T,$
followed by a translation by the vector $(-0.0036,0.1235,-0.9213)^T.$

Similarly, the matrix for $B$ is
$$
M_B = T_{-0.1241,-0.0112,-1.1028} R_{x;-1.01927} R_{y;0.0279253} R_{z;1.60745}.
$$

Now suppose we have a figure $F$ that is transformed by the rotation-translation $A$ into the figure $F_A$, whereas the rotation-translation $B$ transforms the figure $F$ into $F_B.$ Then the transformation that maps $F_B$ to $F_A$ is $B^{-1}$ followed by $A$, and the matrix of that transformation is $M_A M_B^{-1}$ (because, again, the matrix on the right is the matrix for the transformation that occurs first).

The matrix $M_B^{-1} M_A$ is something else altogether. I don't think it does what you think it does.

But since you are asking about a particular matrix you call $M_{BA} = M_B^{-1} M_A$, let's work with that matrix. This matrix works out to the following matrix product:
$$
M_{BA} = T_{-0.0882,-0.1114,0.2131} R_{x;3.12309} R_{y;-0.0248221} R_{z;0.086982}.
$$
Now you should expect that $M_{AB} = M_A^{-1} M_B$ is the inverse of $M_{BA},$
and indeed it is.
You can confirm this by multiplying the two matrices together.
But
$$
M_{AB} = T_{0.0830,-0.1230,0.2088} R_{x;-3.12099} R_{y;-0.0231151} R_{z;0.0874497}.
$$
As you observed, the angles do not match up in any obvious way.

The reason for mismatched angles is that
$$
\left(R_{x;3.12309} R_{y;-0.0248221} R_{z;0.086982}\right)^{-1}
\neq R_{x;3.12309}^{-1} R_{y;-0.0248221}^{-1} R_{z;0.086982}^{-1}.
$$
That is, you don't reverse a sequence of rotations around the $x$ axis, then the $y$ axis, then the $z$ axis by making a sequence of equal (or opposite) rotations around the $x$ axis, then the $y$ axis, then the $z$ axis.
If you want to re-use the angles, write
$$
\left(R_{x;3.12309} R_{y;-0.0248221} R_{z;0.086982}\right)^{-1}
 = R_{z;0.086982}^{-1} R_{y;-0.0248221}^{-1} R_{x;3.12309}^{-1}.
$$
That is, you can undo the sequence of rotations by exactly reversing the last rotation **first**, and then the second rotation, and then finally the first rotation.
But if you insist on rotating around the $x$ axis first both times, both for $M_{BA}$ and also for the inverse transformation $M_{AB},$ you need different sets of angles.
This will generally be true for all but the simplest cases.
Neither matrix multiplication nor transformations in three-D space are commutative in general; in most cases, it matters in what order you do them.

Notice that the components of the translation also don't match;
this is again because the transformations do not commute.
In most cases, if you want to reverse a rotation-and-then-translation using the inverse of the original translation, you have to apply the inverse translation **first**.